# Complicated Join Ignoring 'WHERE EXISTS'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, exists

I am needing to check any promotions that are in the main `USICOAL` database, but not in the snapshot (Simple):

```
SELECT U.[PROMOTION_NO]
      ,U.[STORE_NO]
      ,U.[PROMOTION_NAME]
      ,U.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL START_DATE'
      ,U.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL END_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT START_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT END_DATE'
FROM [REWARDS_SNAPSHOT_2471].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS S
FULL OUTER JOIN [USICOAL].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS U
ON S.PROMOTION_NO = U.PROMOTION_NO
```

But the `USICOAL` database does not show the correct `STORE_NO` (i.e. '8882') instead it will have a random number that is linked on a seperate table (`STORE_GROUP_STORE`) so I have the query below:

```
SELECT UP.STORE_NO
       ,UP.PROMOTION_NO
FROM [USICOAL].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS UP
LEFT JOIN [USICOAL].[dbo].[STORE_GROUP_STORE] AS US
ON UP.STORE_NO = US.STORE_GROUP_ID
WHERE US.STORE_NO = '8882'
```

Both of the above work individually, however the top one is including stores that are not in the query below ('8882') so I tried linking it all together and the query seems to ignore the second part:

```
SELECT U.[PROMOTION_NO]
      ,U.[STORE_NO]
      ,U.[PROMOTION_NAME]
      ,U.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL START_DATE'
      ,U.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL END_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT START_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT END_DATE'
FROM [REWARDS_SNAPSHOT_2471].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS S
FULL OUTER JOIN [USICOAL].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS U
ON S.PROMOTION_NO = U.PROMOTION_NO

WHERE EXISTS

(SELECT UP.STORE_NO
       ,UP.PROMOTION_NO
FROM [USICOAL].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS UP
LEFT JOIN [USICOAL].[dbo].[STORE_GROUP_STORE] AS US
ON UP.STORE_NO = US.STORE_GROUP_ID
WHERE US.STORE_NO = '8882')

AND S.PROMOTION_NO IS NULL
OR U.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME != S.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME
OR U.SCHED_END_DATETIME != S.SCHED_END_DATETIME
```

I know the above is complicated, but due to the database structure I cannot think how to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the bit that adds additional results

```
AND S.PROMOTION_NO IS NULL
OR U.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME != S.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME
OR U.SCHED_END_DATETIME != S.SCHED_END_DATETIME
```

you might want to do this depending on your logic

```
    AND (S.PROMOTION_NO IS NULL
OR U.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME != S.SCHED_BGN_DATETIME
OR U.SCHED_END_DATETIME != S.SCHED_END_DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your outer join back to front. To find rows in U but not in S, select from U left join S:

```
SELECT U.[PROMOTION_NO]
      ,U.[STORE_NO]
      ,U.[PROMOTION_NAME]
      ,U.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL START_DATE'
      ,U.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'USICOAL END_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_BGN_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT START_DATE'
      ,S.[SCHED_END_DATETIME] AS 'SNAPSHOT END_DATE'
FROM [USICOAL].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS U
LEFT JOIN [REWARDS_SNAPSHOT_2471].[dbo].[PROMOTION] AS S
  ON S.PROMOTION_NO = U.PROMOTION_NO
WHERE S.PROMOTION_NO IS NULL
```

This may seem counter-intuitive; how can `S.PROMOTION_NO` equal the key in the main table *and* be null?

The answer is that the join condition is evaluated as the join is made. but the where clause is evaluated *after* the join is made, and when a left join misses, all columns in the joined table are null. Hence, to find all *missed* joins, filter the joined results by keeping only those that have nulls in the joined table.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for all your help!
I finally have the working script and am increadibly relived and it will make our lives allot easier. - Thankyou!